# Compare two vectors in MATLAB without using loop

Tags: matlab, loops, compare

Given two vector `a` , `b` of different length in MATLAB, I want the output as follows:

Example :

```
a = [3 5 10 20 45 80]
b = [3 5 80]
y = [1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

where `y` is of length similar to `a` in which 1's indicate existence of an item in `b` and 0 its non-existence.

I want to do this without using loops. Thanks

Note that all the numbers in each vector will be repeated only once as they correspond to  some ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ismember()](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)

> Lia = ismember(A,B) returns an array containing 1 (true) where the data in A is found in B. Elsewhere, it returns 0 (false).

```
a = [3 5 10 20 45 80];
b = [3 5 80];
ismember(a,b)
```

> ans =
>       1  1  0  0  0  1

Comment: It was late at night so I am indicating the response as an answer.